# AngularJs - Unable to pass object using routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I load some data from the server, and then update the view using `ng-repeat`. The user has the ability to edit the data in another page. Now, is the part where I'm a bit confused. I can pass some parameters using `$routeProvided` combined with `$routeParams`, lets say `id` and fetch the data again from the server depending on that `id`. I believe there's a better way, something like passing the whole `object` to the next controller, rather than conducting another call the server. That's what I've got working right now:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/editPost/:postId/:author', {
      templateUrl: 'editPost.html',
      controller: 'editPostCtrl'
    });
});

app.controller('editPostCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.author + ", " + $routeParams.postId);
});
```

Now, I cant extract the object with the following code:
HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
  <button class="btn" ng-click="editPost(post)">Edit</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/editPost/:post', {
        templateUrl : 'editPost.html',
        controller  : 'editPostCtrl'
    });
});

app.controller('editPostCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.post); //results in [object object]
});
```

Is there a better way for achieving this?

Comment: Use a service to share data across controllers

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong, but data passed by a service won't be available after the browser refreshes. I ended up using `ngCookie`.